# can't insert utf-8 characters in mysql database using crontab to automate the program

Tags: java, mysql, linux, utf-8, cron

I had asked the question before but because I didn't receive any guide, I'm asking it again.
Here's the original question:
[fail to insert non-english characters to database using crontab to run the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652588/fail-to-insert-non-english-characters-to-database-using-crontab-to-run-the-progr)

I wrote a java program that reads from a UTF-8 file and insert its contents to mysql database. I can call jar file in terminal and it works fine. after that I used crontab to automate running the program but this time only english chars and numbers will insert to DB.

My database encoding is "utf8-general-ci" and the server I'm running the program is centOs 6.3.

I should mention that I have another program that its functionality is similar to this and it works fine.

I have tested so many things but none of them fixed the problem. I don't know what's the problem.

I'm looking for a solution or any clue to continue and solve the problem. I'll appreciate any help.

EDIT:
mysql version is :5.1.69

and here is 2 images. one is for the time I run the program with crontab and the other when running the program in terminal

[image]

[image]

Comment: share mysql version and results from "show create table mytable;" in which you are inserting data.

Comment: I have edited the question.please look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not realy an expert on this but here goes nothing.
I think this is related to what's documented in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

Is your default character set on latin1 or something like that ? Perhaps you left it default and i think it then uses latin1.

In any case i think you have to do something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE target_table_name MODIFY latin1_text_col TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE target_table_name MODIFY latin1_varchar_col VARCHAR(M) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

You can find out the default char set of the database by doing:

```
use db_name;
show variables like "character_set_database";
show variables like "collation_database";
```

Comment: thanks for your attention. but as I said before my collation is utf8_general_ci. I just checked the collation again and it is utf8_general_ci. I'm really confused. and the thing makes me more confused is that the program works fine when run it in the terminal and it doesn't work when run it with crontab

Comment: Thank you. My collation was utf8 but my table columns were something else and running this command on each column in question allowed me to insert utf8 characters:

ALTER TABLE target_table_name MODIFY target_column TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anyway to fix the problem so I wrote a schedular program that runs the application and it works fine!!!

But I'm still confused why crontab makes that problem or what I did that program doesn't work fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have set you db, table, and columns using utf8mb4, **don't forget
specify your connection to mysql using utf8 charset**:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://ip:port/db?characterEncoding=utf8";
String username = "xxx";
String password = "xxx";

try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

--

I'm curious about the root cause of your problems as well...